# When a hard drive is cloned, will the certificates in IIS be cloned as well?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, cloning

I want to upgrade my mechanical hd with SSD. I have a number of SSL certificates that I "created" and "completed" on the IIS server. My question is when I clone the mechanical hd with SSD, will the certificates be cloned as well?

Comment: Yes. Why would they not be? A clone, as it's name implies, is an exact copy.

Comment: The machine keys/certs are on your hard drive `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto` unless you have some kind of hardware security module (HSM) or something.